# How to fix this "Tailwind CSS Deprecation" error?

Tags: css, visual-studio-code, tailwind-css

Whenever I try to rebuild my src/styles.css file, it throws me this "deprecation" error, and due to this error whatever changes I make in my src/styles.css are not getting reflected. How should I avoid this error? Because of this, I'm not able to run any custom CSS code.

```
PS D:\TailwindCSS\TailwindWebsiteProject> npm run build-css

> tailwindwebsiteproject@1.0.0 build-css D:\TailwindCSS\TailwindWebsiteProject
> tailwindcss build src/styles.css -o 
public/styles.css

**[deprecation] Running tailwindcss without -i, please provide an input file.**

Done in 6559ms.
PS D:\TailwindCSS\TailwindWebsiteProject>
```

package.json file snippet

[image]

Comment: Change your `build-css` script in `package.json` to be `tailwindcss build -i src/styles.css -o public/styles.css`

Comment: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/installation#using-a-custom-css-file

Comment: Please don't post pictures of text. Copy the original text to your question and use the code format tool.

Answer (score 0):

I am not very familiar with tailwind css, but according to the error I see, you are running the command without the `-i` flag. So whatever command you are entering or in the script that you are running add this flag and again reading the error I suppose you should mention a filename after the `-i`. You can check the docs to see what file has to be mentioned here. (Scripts are in your package.json file, they are run every time you run the corresponding key as a command in the terminal)